# Storing API keys for react redux apps

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react applications and want to store google places API key. At the moment i have those scripts with keys in my index.html file, where should i place those keys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally, your keys should come from your configuration/environment files. This will 
 give you the flexibility of using different keys for different environments.

Create a file called .env.development.local/.env.production and add keys there like 'REACT_APP_GOOGLE_PLACES_API_KEY'.

Now, create a config file named config.js and add the following line to it 'export const GOOGLE_PLACES_API_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_PLACES_API_KEY'.

Now, import this config file in your components and use the exported values.

This way you can drive your keys just from the environment files.

Comment: should'nt i use REACT_APP prefix with it.?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `.env` file in your project root and load the keys using process.env.{KEY_NAME} for example

If you are using `create-react-app` .env gets automatically loaded

```
in your .env file

REACT_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN='ae88b51e-cb87-4c9d-a3e3-7c2e2ffc3134'; //REACT_APP_{KEY_NAME} REACT_APP is mandatory
```

and you can access the key in react using

```
process.env.REACT_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

If you are not using create-react-app you can integrate the dotenv package from [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) link

Comment: does it need to be a string like 'something'?

Comment: @FazalKarim yes, event if you declare a number in `.env` it will give you string itself

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use the `googleapi` package on npm:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis

Usually sensitive data (API Keys) should be injected as environment variables.
Either set them in your hosting environment or during build time.
Since your are building a React application you are most likely using webpack, I guess.
Webpack allows you to inject them into your code: https://webpack.js.org/guides/environment-variables/
As an alternative you could also use this handy plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack which allows you to use `.env` files

If you are using `create-react-app` it already supports such feature. Make sure to prefix your environment variables with `REACT_APP`: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables

Important: Since this is a client side application you still expose your API credentials and there is no way around this. Make sure to whitelist your dev / prod environment in the Google service if possible or run your own proxy server (which is a little more complicated and takes some setup).

Comment: i have my key in a .env file and using this script in index.html, but getting an invalidKeyMapError

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_PLACES_API_KEY&libraries=places"></script>